# Generar un archivo tar a partir de un script

Tags: bash, script, debian, tar

Estoy generando un script para el respaldo de archivos pero quiero mostrarlo con una barra de progreso, todo bien pero al intentar generar el archivo tar no lo hace

```
  # copiamos los archivos de $f a $DEST
  /bin/tar -cfz $f_$FECHA_Y_HORA.tar $f ${DEST} &>/dev/null
   done
)
```

Si borro el directorio, si lo vuelve a crear pero no genera el .tar
al copiarlo si funciona

```
/bin/cp $f ${DEST} &/dev/null
```

Dejo las variables

```
FECHA_Y_HORA=`date "+%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S"`
DIRS=("/home/sistemas/Respaldo.sh")

# Directorio de destino
DEST="/media/sistemas/storage1/Respaldos/"

for f in "${DIRS[@]}"
   do
```

Ya logre crearlo aunque no en la misma sentencia pero funciono

```
 # comprimimos los archivos de $f
  /bin/tar -czvf RespaldoVMware_$FECHA_Y_HORA.tar.gz $DIRS

  # movemos el tar a $DEST 
  /bin/mv $DirTar/*.tar.gz ${DEST} &/dev/null
```

Pero ahora quisiera que verifique el archivo y si existe lo elimine para que lo pueda escribir nuevamente, lo use con los operadores logicos pero no lo elimina

```
[ ! -f $DEST/RespaldoVMware_*.tar.gz] &&  rm $DEST/RespaldoVMware_*.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logre hacer el Script por si a alguien le sirve o funciona dejo el código

```
#!/bin/bash
# Respaldo.sh: Es un Script que respalda la informacion de las maquinas virtuales
#         Mostrando el progreso en una barra.
# --------------------------------------------------------
FECHA_Y_HORA=`date "+%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S"`
# Directorio donde se guarda el tar.gz
DirTar=("/home/sistemas/")
# Directorio a respaldar 
DIRS=("/home/sistemas/Respaldo.sh")

# Directorio de destino
DEST="/media/sistemas/storage1/Respaldos/"

# Creamos $DEST si este no existe
[ ! -d $DEST ] && mkdir -p $DEST


#
# Mostramos el progreso
# ---------------------------------
# Redireccionamos el dialogo
#
dialog --title "Respaldando Archivos" --gauge "Respaldando Archivos..." 10 75 < <(
   # Tomamos el total de los arreglos
   n=${#DIRS[*]};

   # Asignamos el contador
   i=0

   #
   # Inicio del loop
   #
   # Leemos los archivos $DIRS 
   # $f es una fila de archivos 
   for f in "${DIRS[@]}"
   do
      # calculamos el progreso
      PCT=$(( 100*(++i)/n ))

      # Actualizamos el estado
cat <<EOF
XXX
$PCT
Respaldando Archivos "$f"...
XXX
EOF

  #Si existe el archivo lo borramos 
  [ -f $DEST/*.tar.gz ] && rm -r &DEST/*.tar.gz

  # comprimimos los archivos de $f
  /bin/tar -czvf RespaldoVMware_$FECHA_Y_HORA.tar.gz $DIRS

  # movemos el tar a $DEST 
  /bin/mv $DirTar/*.tar.gz ${DEST} &/dev/null

  done

)
  clear
```